# my page seems like to be tiny like i zoomed out

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I am looking for a slider for my website and i found one but i don't understand why it is zooming out my page so the navbar seems tiny like if was on a 70% scale and if I don't use this code anymore it get back to normal

Here is the code from the example I used

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
  var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
  var itemWidth = "";

  $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function() {
    var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
    if (condition)
      click(0, this);
    else
      click(1, this)
  });

  ResCarouselSize();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    ResCarouselSize();
  });

  //this function define the size of the items
  function ResCarouselSize() {
    var incno = 0;
    var dataItems = ("data-items");
    var itemClass = ('.item');
    var id = 0;
    var btnParentSb = '';
    var itemsSplit = '';
    var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
    var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
    $(itemsDiv).each(function() {
      id = id + 1;
      var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
      btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
      itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
      $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);


      if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
        incno = itemsSplit[3];
        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
      } else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
        incno = itemsSplit[2];
        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
      } else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
        incno = itemsSplit[1];
        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
      } else {
        incno = itemsSplit[0];
        itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
      }
      $(this).css({
        'transform': 'translateX(0px)',
        'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers
      });
      $(this).find(itemClass).each(function() {
        $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
      });

      $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
      $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

    });
  }


  //this function used to move the items
  function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
    var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
    var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
    var translateXval = '';
    var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
    var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
    var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
    if (e == 0) {
      translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
      $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

      if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
        translateXval = 0;
        $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
      }
    } else if (e == 1) {
      var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
      translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
      $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

      if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
        translateXval = itemsCondition;
        $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
      }
    }
    $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
  }

  //It is used to get some elements from btn
  function click(ell, ee) {
    var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
    var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
    ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
  }

});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner {
  transition: 1s ease all;
  float: left;
}

.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item {
  float: left;
}

.MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item>div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #666;
}

.MultiCarousel .leftLst,
.MultiCarousel .rightLst {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.MultiCarousel .leftLst {
  left: 0;
}

.MultiCarousel .rightLst {
  right: 0;
}

.MultiCarousel .leftLst.over,
.MultiCarousel .rightLst.over {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel" data-interval="1000">
      <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="pad15">
            <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
            <p>₹ 1</p>
            <p>₹ 6000</p>
            <p>50% off</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst">&lt;</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">&gt;</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <br/><br/><br/>
      <hr/>
      <p>Settings</p>
      <p>Change data items for xs,sm,md and lg display items respectively. Ex:data-items="1,3,5,6"</p>
      <p>Change data slide for slides per click Ex:data-slide="1"</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit :

[Tiny navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pATfh.png)

So as you can see the navbar in this page is realy tiny but not in my other pages

edit 2 :

So i found the problem it is this

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
      <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But i need this or i can't slide on my carousel

I have no idea what I need to so thanks for your help and sorry for my English

Comment: To repeat what you've said:  you have some code that messes up your website, if you don't use the code it doesn't mess up your site.  So... don't use the code?

Comment: You should consider using sensible *and consistent* variable names - your click is called with `ell` - which *looks like* "element" but is just 0/1 - this gets passed to `ResCarousel` as `e` (which *also* looks like "element").

Comment: TBH: you're best solution is to step through using the console debugger tools (add the command `debugger;` at the top of your left/right click handler.

Comment: The issue is *most likely* around `var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");`  - you'll be better off passing jquery objects around rather than extract `id` attributes and prepending "#".  Insread of `$(e + ' ' + right)` use `$e.find(right)`.

Comment: another hint might be an "error" in your meta viewport tag (if existent) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Converted to snippet.  **Note** you were getting an error because bootstrap3 needs to be *after* jquery.   Your page works fine either way *in the snippet*.   Please [edit] the question / code to provide a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.

Comment: thx for your help freedom i edited so you can the result on my website of the problem. I need to use this code cause i need a carousel and this the only one that works. I will try what you said thx